# How to add new DNS entries for website

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a registered site registerd under other  `Provider1` . I want to use it with `Provider2` server for that I have changed mywebsites DNS at `Provider1` hosting provider.
second step I have create A record `mysite.com` and IP address.

Now I am writing my site name at address bar that is not redirection it to my `Provider2' server. what extra confirutation needed ???

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  For example:  Are Provider1 and Provider2 two separate hosting services?  Are you trying to move your website from one to the other?  Or redirect from Provider2 to your site on Provider1?  And, where is your DNS being hosted at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the question as follows:

1) You have bought a domain from Provider1. This is your domain registrar and you can manage your DNS record within their interface.

2) You have bought a website hosting from Provider2. This is a different company.

3) You want to connect your DNS record with your hosting so that if you type mysite.com into browser, you will see your pages loading.

4) You know IP address (let's assume it is 1.2.3.4) of the web hosting server with Provider2 and you have already created DNS A record that says mysite.com is 1.2.3.4.

5) It does not work.

If this describes your situation well, then there are two things I can think of that can go wrong:

A) You created the DNS record, but did not wait long enough for the record to be propagated world wide and the DNS server that you use for your address resolving, does not have this updated record yet. You can use [DNS Propagation Checker](http://dns-propagation-checker.online-domain-tools.com/) to get information on how well is your DNS record propagated over the distributed network. You can also [flush your local DNS cache](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+To+Clear+Your+DNS+Cache) to prevent your operating system local cache from giving you the old records.

B) You have not inform Provider2 that your hosting program should accept requests for mysite.com. How to fix this depends entirely on your web hosting provider's interface. However, you can tell if this is the case if you put your address into the browser and different page than you expect (which is your web application page) is displayed to you.

Comment: I checked at  that is showing `All servers see the same version.` http://dns-propagation-checker.online-domain-tools.com/

Comment: I tried curl www.sitename.com is showing return only my chrome browser is not shoing any thing I tested on ther browser working properly